# Column data type affected by usage of it elsewhere

Tags: python, sqlite, apsw

I can't seem to find a reference to the following behavior either in SQLite or [apsw](https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw) docs:

I have a table partially defined and populated as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE GeoLoc (lat TEXT, lon TEXT);
INSERT INTO GeoLoc (lat, lon) VALUES ('-33.5533422', '151.23422');
```

When using [apsw](https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw) to get the result for:

```sql
SELECT lat FROM GeoLoc;
```

I get the correct `unicode` value type for `lat` column. But running:

```sql
SELECT lat FROM GeoLoc WHERE lat + 0 = lat + 0;
```

I get `float` type instead! The above example is a silly one, but in my actual query, I'm doing some calculations with `lat` that turns it into floating point type but I don't expect the type to change *everywhere* in my query.

I rely on exact value of `lat` as I stored it. When converted to float, [it could change when cast back to string](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) (see section 4.0).

Note: I get the same result with Python's SQLite3 module, <s>but *not* from</s> as well as SQLite3's own command line client.

Comment: Yet other strange examples are `SELECT lat FROM GeoLoc WHERE lat = lat OR lat + 0 = lat + 0` which gives `unicode` result. But reversing the conditions gives `float`!

Comment: What SQLite versions are you using?

Comment: And the command-line shell?

Comment: It's the same version

Comment: Really? I do get the bug in the command-line shell.

Comment: How does it manifest? I'm not very fluent in the shell, as in how do you tell the field value type in the shell?

Comment: OK, I set the mode to insert and you're right, I do get the same behavior in the shell.

Comment: [SQLite ticket](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/info/a8a0d2996a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/info/a8a0d2996a) that was [introduced](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/info/58704ed1f4cd78bb) in SQLite version 3.8.3.
Now [fixed](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/info/221f8f9447).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. Actually when using sqlite3 `CAST`, it seems to work fine:

```sql
SELECT CAST(lat AS TEXT) FROM GeoLoc WHERE lat + 0 = lat + 0;
```

To test it, I used a very high precision floating point (e.g. 80 significant figures) and the above returned it verbatim. Appending an empty string seems to work just as well:

```sql
SELECT lat || '' FROM GeoLoc WHERE lat + 0 = lat + 0;
```

But, I'm still wondering why the default behavior is to change the data type all across. At least viewed from a programmer's eyes, this is unnatural. You only expect an automatic cast to occur at the usage point.